Issues showing counterexamples in VSCode's Dafny plugin
I've been using Dafny in VSCode for a few weeks now and have never been able to view counterexamples for failed assertions.
Every time I request a counterexample a small box appears in the bottom right corner with the message.
Counterexample request failed: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

It seems like this is an issue with the plugin itself. So I wondered if I had done something wrong during set up.
I have uninstalled Dafny and the VSCode plugin, then reinstalled both and yet I still run into this issue.
I'm not sure if there is a fix for this.
Using information from this post https://brandonrozek.com/blog/dafny-3-3-countermodel/, I can use the command line tool to view a counterexample. However, I find it very unreadable.
Is there another way to view and interpret Dafny counterexamples?

Apparently it was broken a few weeks ago, and the PR to fix it is still pending.
https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/pull/5847
This is a regression; You can use the previous version of Dafny in the meanwhile, the 4.8.1 one
